# web-scraping using python ('NoneType' object is not iterable)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and web-scraping. I am trying to scrape a website (link is the url). I am getting an error as "'NoneType' object is not iterable", with the last line of below code. Could anyone point what could have gone wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = 'https://labtestsonline.org/tests-index'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')

# Function to get hyper-links for all test components
hyperlinks = []
def parseUrl(url):
    global hyperlinks
    page = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
    for a in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'field-content'}):
        a = a.find('a')
        href = urlparse.urljoin(Url,a.get('href'))
        hyperlinks.append(href)



parseUrl(url)

# function to get header and common questions for each test component
def header(url):
    page = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
h = []
commonquestions = []
for head in soup.find('div',{'class':'field-item'}).find('h1'):
    heading = head.get_text()
    h.append(heading)
for q in soup.find('div',{'id':'Common_Questions'}):
    questions = q.get_text()
    commonquestions.append(questions)

for i in range(0, len(hyperlinks)):
    header(hyperlinks[i])
```

Below is the traceback error:

```
<ipython-input-50-d99e0af6db20> in <module>()
1 for i in range(0, len(hyperlinks)):
2     header(hyperlinks[i])
<ipython-input-49-15ac15f9071e> in header(url)
5     soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
6     h = []
for head in soup.find('div',{'class':'field-item'}).find('h1'):
heading = head.get_text()
h.append(heading)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: In which line you are getting error ?

Comment: Please add the *full* error traceback to your question!

Comment: @VikasDamodar the last line i.e the for-loop

Comment: can you just check your code indentation and make changes ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar i have added the error traceback

Comment: @KlausD.  I have added the error traceback

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find('div',{'class':'field-item'}).find('h1')` is returning `None`. First check whether the function returns anything before looping over it.

Something like:

```
heads = soup.find('div',{'class':'field-item'}).find('h1')
if heads:
    for head in heads:
        # remaining code
```

Comment: i have done what you have suggested. It is throwing this error: AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should solve the issues you are having at this moment. I used css selector to get the job done.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

link = 'https://labtestsonline.org/tests-index'
page = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
for a in soup.select('.field-content a'):
    new_link = urljoin(link,a.get('href'))   ##joining broken urls so as to reuse these
    response = requests.get(new_link)        ##sending another http requests
    sauce = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
    for item in sauce.select("#Common_Questions .field-item"):
        print(item.text)
    print("<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>")
```